# Building 2 layer neural network with Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a simple 2 layer network, it has 2 inputs and 1 output, and the code is as follows:

```
num_input = 2
num_output = 1

# Input
x1 = torch.rand(1, 2)

# Weights
W1 = torch.rand(2,3)
W2 = torch.rand(3,1)

# biases
b1 = torch.rand(1,3)
b2 = torch.rand(1,1)

# Activation function
def f(inp):
    inp[inp >= 0] = 1
    inp[inp < 0] = 0
    return inp

# Predict output
out = f(torch.mm(x1, W1) + b1)
y=W2*out +b2
print(y)

# Check solution
assert list(y.size()) == [1, num_output], f"Incorrect output size ({y.size()})"
print("nice!")
```

from this code I always get incorrect output size, can anyone give me a hint, how can I get the correct output size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y=out@W2 +b2
```

You were doing elementwise multiplication. That was not changing the size of the output as you desired.

Just to be clear `python 3.5` and above can use this "@" syntax - which is doing the same thing as `torch.mm()` - that is matrix multiplication.

##### Dimensions: (Now)

Now you have `(1,2)` input multiplied with `(2,3)` weights and adding `(1,3)` bias. Shape is `(1,3)` and then you matrix mutiply with `(1,3)` and `(3,1)` output is `(1,1)` and bias to it making the final output size `(1,1)`.

[image]

##### Dimensions (before)

[image]

###### Side Note:

Also you can use the `nn.Linear` to do all these operations easily without specifying the weights and biases like that.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation